# Docker Desktop in Mac OS (High Sierra) showing Kubernetes is staring forever. Kubectl shows Unable to connect to the server: EOF

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I upgraded to docker stable version 2.0.0.3 running in my local. Earlier I had docker CE 17.06 which only had docker and kubernetes options were missing. 
When I ran `kubectl cluster-info dump` I get the output in terminal.

How can I fix this? I have 3 docker containers fir which I wanted to run in Kubernetes now instead of using docker networks all alone. When running `kubectl cluster-info` this is the output-

> Kubernetes master is running at https://localhost:6443

Comment: did you get any solution ? @bosari

Comment: @Mezbah noi did not

Comment: do you have any alternative idea?